# How to create custom liquid/markdown tags in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

This Jekyll markdown + HTML code works fine:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8"  markdown="1">

**Lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec eros eget nisl fringilla commodo. Maecenas ornare, augue ut ultricies tristique, enim lectus pretium quam, quis bibendum metus tellus sed magna. Donec eu dolor augue ut ultricies tristique, enim lectus pretium quam, quis bibendum metus tellus sed magna.

</div><div class="col-md-4" markdown="1">
![](images/exercise.jpg)
</div></div>
```

But I'd like to avoid HTML in markdown, to control styling & grid system  only in 1 place (eg upgrade to bootstrap 4 or change entire template)

How could something like this work instead?

```
{% grid %} 
{% col:8 %}

**Lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec eros eget nisl fringilla commodo. Maecenas ornare, augue ut ultricies tristique, enim lectus pretium quam, quis bibendum metus tellus sed magna. Donec eu dolor augue ut ultricies tristique, enim lectus pretium quam, quis bibendum metus tellus sed magna.    

{% col:4 %}
![](images/exercise.jpg)
{% endgrid %}
```

Any syntax without HTML is welcome, this is just an example.

Comment: I guess it's not in the spirit of markdown to do layout with rows and columns there. Write some custom CSS instead of using bootstrap and you won't have to write all those ugly divs...

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/). This lets you add content from another file to your HTML.

So you would have something like a file named `grid-start.html` in your `_includes` directory that contained the `<div class="row">` HTML. Similar for the `<div class="col-md-8"  markdown="1">` content, as well as closing tags. Also note that you can pass in parameters to an include file.

Then in your markdown, you would do something like this:

```
{% include grid-start.html %}
   {% include col-start col="8" %}
      **Lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet...
   {% include col-end %}  
   {% include col-start col="4" %}
      ![](images/exercise.jpg)
   {% include col-end %}  
{% grid-end %}
```

Honestly this seems like a lot of rigmarole just to avoid using some basic html tags though.

Comment: Appreciate the solution, Kevin! We'll stick to the html code, it is simpler indeed.

Comment: @MariusAndreiana You might also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667472/integrating-column-support-into-markdown-in-jekyll-framework) that was just asked, which points to [this](https://github.com/dreikanter/markdown-grid) Markdown extension. It's old and might not be maintained anymore, but maybe you could use it for inspiration.