# Integrating column support into markdown in Jekyll framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I'd like to add functionality for dynamic columning, similar to a bootstrap grid system, in text posts within a Jekyll blog (which comes with kramdown by default). Ideally this would be done easily in markdown posts. I found this github project that seems like exactly what I'd need:

https://github.com/dreikanter/markdown-grid

I've looked through this project but, unfortunately, I don't have much experience with frontend and I'm not sure where to start to integrate this into my Jekyll template, or if this is even possible. Any insights appreciated.

EDIT: Like I said, I don't have much experience with this so if this is a bad question, please let me know why instead of just downvoting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that people are down voting you without explaining why.

Anyways, I recommend you practice using a front-end framework such as [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). They have tutorials on their website, and their example project is pretty straightforward. Once you figure out how to use their grid system, you can then implement it into your jekyll site.

Jekyll sites typically use templates. You can edit the base template to "include" the Foundation (or variant, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)) so that it is available throughout every page on your site. Then, you can edit other templates (such as where the blogs are displayed) utilizing the provided CSS classes.

I hope this answer pointed you in the right direction.